# jquery set timeout run once then replace by other function

Tags: jquery, settimeout

i need delay the function more for first time, then delay normal for future

```
  var delaytime = 2000;
  var $this = $(this);
```

then

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.addClass('show');
  }, 5000 + delaytime);
```

anyway to run above function only once, then replace by below function? (remove 5000 delay)

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.addClass('show');
  }, delaytime);
```

i have try on, off method, seem not work, please give me some hint, thanks so much :)

Comment: Do you have a loop or is it supposed to happend just two times ?

Comment: this will happend alot of time :) each time $this have .active class then run function, but i need first time delay more :) thanks

Comment: Ok so this is happening on an event, not looping like all the answers below. Can you provide the code where you add the `.active` class ?

Comment: why you know this is by event??? yes it a afterLoad event, the code have variable at other function, i dont know how to make a demo for this function, next time i will note all detail here, thanks so much, you below answer work for me!!! thanks :)

Comment: I guessed it because that was quite a strange idea otherwise ! Glad it helped.

Comment: i need add the show class after preloader first time, i cant run my function by preloader callback, maybe because the event inside a function setting?  so try this idea, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9xszkv0/)**

If you want this delay to happen on mouseover event for example, I think this is what you want :

```
$('.myelement').on('mouseover', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var delaytime = $this.hasClass('notfirsttime') ? 2000 : 7000;

    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.addClass('show notfirsttime');
    }, delaytime);
});
```

You might also want to `clearTimeout` on `mouseout` :

```
var mouseOverTimeout = null;
$('.myelement').on('mouseover', function(){
    /* code */
});
$('.myelement').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    clearTimeout(mouseOverTimeout);
});
```

Comment: wow...i am not use mouseover, this run when 'afterLoad' event on plugin, i add class to body, your answer work for me, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a function and pass the timeout as a parameter

```
var delaytime = 2000;
var $this = $(this);

function rundelay(delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.addClass('show');
        rundelay(delaytime);  
    }, delay);
}

rundelay(5000 + delaytime);
```

Comment: What the `if (delay == 5000 + delaytime) delay = delaytime;` for ?

Comment: Since the first time delay is being passed as 5000+delaytime, it simply replaces it for the first time, after that it will never be 5000 + delaytime, so its just a one time check.

Comment: I think you should move this line inside the `setTimeout`. Think about it... What would happend ?

Comment: I will edit your answer and you will tell if you agree with the changes

Comment: i already edited my answer, but you are welcome to further modify it, but i guess it should work fine now.

Comment: this not work for my code, its my code problem, i try your code at other demo, the code work :) thanks:) like

Answer (score 1):

Set the shorter timeout inside the function that get's executed inside the timeout.

Then call this function via timeout with the longer delay:

```
function timeoutTrigger(){
    var out = $('#out');

    out.text(out.text() + '.');
    // Place here what should happen every iteration, like
    // $this.addClass('show');

    setTimeout(timeoutTrigger, 250); // Short delay
};

setTimeout(timeoutTrigger, 1500); // Long initial delay
```

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6a0db6rq/

Comment: thanks :) this not work for me, but, yes i see your demo, work perfect !!! my code problem, thanks for you nice answer and demo :) like

Answer (score 0):

This code will do for you

```
var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $this.addClass('show');
    timer = setTimeout(function myfunction() {

    }, 4000);
}, 5000);
```